# Concatenate/merge several rows within ONE pandas dataframe, based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which several rows share a particular column value. For those, I want to concatenate/merge these into one single row (sometimes the column value will only appear once in the table, maximum 5 times, so in the end the rows would have variable lengths). I also want the data to be sorted by date (ascending).

The data looks something like this:

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'Funded_Venture': ['Helia', 'Loop', 'Asana', 'Helia', 'Helia', 'Loop'], 
'Funding Type': ['Seed', 'Seed', 'Series A', 'Series B', 'Series C', 'Series A'],
'Money Raised': [500000,200000,1000000,250000,300000,200000], 
'Announced_Date': ['01/10/2006', '03/03/2007', '04/08/2008', '10/12/2008', '20/06/2009', '30/09/2009'], 
'Investor.1': ['Public VC', 'Private VC', 'Public VC', 'Public VC', 'Private VC', 'Company'], 
'Investor.2': ['Public VC', '', 'Public VC', 'Public VC', '', 'Angel Investor'], 
'Investor.3': ['Incubation Funding', 'Public VC', 'Public VC', '', 'Angel Investor', 'Public VC']})
```

(The actual dataset has about 750 columns and 15 rows)

I am stuck here:

```
df1['Announced_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Announced_Date'])
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['Announced_Date', 'Funded_Venture'],
                      ascending=[True, True])
df1['number of rounds'] = iv_chain.groupby('Funded_Venture').cumcount().add(1)
df1 = df1.merge(df1, on=['Funded_Venture'], how='inner')
df1.to_csv('df1.csv', index=False, sep=";")
```

The outcome for now is that it creates several rows with different combinations.

I would like to have one row where all Helia Funding can be found starting from the first date, one row where all the Loop Funding can be found etc.

The result I am looking for would look something like this:

```
Funded_Venture;Funding Type_x;Money Raised_x;Announced_Date_x;Investor.1_x;Investor.2_x;Investor.3_x;number of rounds_x;Funding Type_y;Money Raised_y;Announced_Date_y;Investor.1_y;Investor.2_y;Investor.3_y;number of rounds_y;Funding Type_z;Money Raised_z;Announced_Date_z;Investor.1_z;Investor.2_z;Investor.3_z;number of rounds_z
Helia;Seed;500000;2006-01-10;Public VC;Public VC;Incubation Funding;1;Series B;250000;2008-10-12;Public VC;Public VC;;2;Series C;300000;2009-06-20;Private VC;;Angel Investor;3
Loop;Seed;200000;2007-03-03;Private VC;;Public VC;1;Series A;200000;2009-09-30;Company;Angel Investor;Public VC;2
Asana;Series A;1000000;2008-04-08;Public VC;Public VC;Public VC;1
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your wanted result if you want them grouped by sum:

```
df1.groupby('Funded_Venture').sum()
```

it give you this result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, I do not want them grouped, I would like the row to extend and keep the labels of the investors. Probably should specify the result I want to get in my question above, will adjust it.

Comment: okey , i m waiting for your specification of the output , it will make it clearer

Comment: Thank you, the desired output is now specified above

Comment: it feels you will lose data in doing so, for their combination to put  them in the same row , you should redefine the names of the columns so that they will be different and we can separate them example for funding_type_x , Seed for 3 of them however they difference up in Investor.3_x

Comment: can you give us example of the iv_chain?

Comment: So one iv_chain is above in the dataset, the example of Helia. It has three funding rounds (Seed, Series A, Series B) on three dates (2006-01-10, 2008-10-12, 2009-06-20) with various investor types investing in these rounds. Whereas Loop only has 2 founding rounds and Asana 1 fr. I would like to extend the dataframe by the length of this investment chain, so that all the information for Helia as a funded_venture can be found in one row (for now it is in 3 rows).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `unstack`. Since you want to group results by the round number, that information needs to be added to the DataFrame.

I added the `Round` column manually, which should be automated for larger DataFrames:

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({
'Funded_Venture': ['Helia', 'Loop', 'Asana', 'Helia', 'Helia', 'Loop'],
'Round': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
'Funding Type': ['Seed', 'Seed', 'Series A', 'Series B', 'Series C', 'Series A'],
'Money Raised': [500000,200000,1000000,250000,300000,200000], 
'Announced_Date': ['01/10/2006', '03/03/2007', '04/08/2008', '10/12/2008', '20/06/2009', '30/09/2009'], 
'Investor.1': ['Public VC', 'Private VC', 'Public VC', 'Public VC', 'Private VC', 'Company'], 
'Investor.2': ['Public VC', '', 'Public VC', 'Public VC', '', 'Angel Investor'], 
'Investor.3': ['Incubation Funding', 'Public VC', 'Public VC', '', 'Angel Investor', 'Public VC']
})
```

Running

```
df1.set_index(['Funded_Venture', 'Round']).unstack()
```

seems to yield some useful results.

[image: Jupyter Notebook DataFrame output]

Hope this helps!